# How to fix "uncaught syntax error" in jquery autocomplete CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want to create an autocomplete feature in a search box and I plan to use jquery autocomplete. I used the last three links available here (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-autocomplete) in my HTML in the form of:

```
<script src="LINK"></script>
```

But before I wrote any code, I see "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token." in my inspector for both the min.css and css.map files. This seems to be a problem with the linked files. Are there other links I should use for CDNs for jQuery? Thank you.

Comment: Read about how to include CSS files on W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a **javascript** syntax error because you try to load some **css** instructions in your `<script>` tags!
You should just load your css files in regular `link` tags, i.e.:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=""https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.css"">
```

Hope it helps!